# TF SavedModel has fixed input size after conversion of GPT-2 to ONNX and TF.js

Tags: python, tensorflow

The input to GPT-2 can be up to 1024 tokens, and yet when I export the Hugging Face GPT-2 model as a TF `SavedModel` like this:

```sh
pip install transformers
```

```py
from transformers import TFGPT2LMHeadModel
model = TFGPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')
model.save("./gpt2_tf_saved_model", save_format="tf")
```

and then I convert it to an ONNX model like this:

```sh
pip install -U tf2onnx
python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model ./gpt2_tf_saved_model --output ./gpt2.onnx
```

then what I find (when visualizing it with [netron.app](https://netron.app/)) is that the resulting model has a fixed input size of 5 tokens. The batch size is `-1`/`unk` though, so it seems that the converter has no trouble with creating variable input shapes, but for some reason it has fixed the token context length at 5.

I've also tried converting to TensorFlow.js:

```sh
pip install tensorflowjs
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format tf_saved_model ./gpt2_tf_saved_model ./gpt2_tfjs_model
```

and I get the same result. I've also tried changing the opset version for the ONNX conversion, but this does not help. I wasn't able to get the visualization of the `SavedModel` .pb file working properly in Netron, so I'm not sure if this is something wrong with the `SavedModel` itself, or the conversion process, or my newbie understanding of this whole process.